# Парсинг html стандартными средствами???

Tags: python, синтаксический-анализ

Будующий скрипт будет использоваться на множестве машин в организации. Я заведомо не могу знать что там на них установлено. Так вот, какие модули использовать, что все работало 100% и не надо было ничего скачивать и устанавливать? Есть что-то штатное кроме регеспов?
И последнее! Возможно что сриптик сконвертируеться в exe с помощью PyInstaller. Если я все таки буду использовать те модули которые надо устанавливать, они попадут в этот exe или нет?

Comment: по теме могу только сказать, что парсинг html технически сложная задача, т.к. он (html) не обязательно является полным и правильным.

Например, <div><p></div> - каким образом вы будете парсить эту строку? А строки такого вида вполне возможны на различных сайтах.

Надеяться на то, что код страниц всегда будет правильным я бы не стал, тем более, что надо, чтобы "все работало 100%".

Если же вы уверены, что код будет правильным, а неправильным можно пренебречь, то можно копать в сторону XML - теги html по сути являются XML-разметкой (это по хорошему, но так далеко не всегда - читай выше)

Comment: Не пытайтесь. Парсинг HTML при помощи regexp'ов очень сложен и трудоёмок, вот [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/276994).

Comment: я уверен в том, что html будет правильный. Надо будет поговрить с отделом web разработки чтоб они поправили.

Comment: так вы собираетесь парсить свои же страницы? а зачем?

если нужны какие-то данные со страницы, то почему бы не получать эти данные напрямую, например с какого-нибудь REST-сервиса,

т.е., например, вам надо получить список групп товаров. Вместо парсинга html для получения этого списка групп, вы обращаетесь по какому-нибудь адресу и получаете уже готовый список в формате JSON

Или вам не для этого надо? Тогда для чего? Может вы аналог своего браузера пишите? Смущает то, что хотите парсить собственные (а не чужие) страницы.

Comment: Что вы собираетесь парсить? Полностью всю страницу, или только некоторые данные?